# Jpa projection don't set value

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have two table who are not linked directly with a foreign key.

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@IdClass(CodeTablePK.class)
public class Codetable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "codetable_Sequence")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "codetable_Sequence", sequenceName = "CODETABLE_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    private Integer codeId;

    @Id
    private String codeType;

    private Long labelId;

}

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@IdClass(LabelPK.class)
public class Label extends BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "label_Sequence")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "label_Sequence", sequenceName = "LABEL_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    private Long labelId;

    @Id
    private String labelLanguage;

    private String labelText;

}

@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class LabelPK implements Serializable {

    private Long labelId;
    private String labelLanguage;

}
```

I created a query to link both table on their labelId.
Projection is not mapped

```
@Repository
public interface CodetableRepository extends JpaRepository<Codetable, Long> {

    @Query(value = "select  c.codeId, l.labelId, l.labelLanguage, l.labelText  from  Codetable c inner join Label l on c.labelId=l.labelId where c.codeType=:codeType")
    public List<CodetablePayload> findByCodeType(@Param("codeType") String codeType);

}

public interface CodetablePayload {

    Integer getCodeId();
    Long getLabelId();
    String getLabelLanguage();
    String getLabelText();

}
```

Query executed is ok

```
select
        codetable0_.code_id as col_0_0_,
        label1_.label_id as col_1_0_,
        label1_.label_language as col_2_0_,
        label1_.label_text as col_3_0_ 
    from
        codetable codetable0_ 
    inner join
        label label1_ 
            on (
                codetable0_.label_id=label1_.label_id
            ) 
    where
        codetable0_.code_type=?
```

In sql that return me two row.

Jpa return me two object with null value.

Why the mapping is nto done

Comment: Is it correct that ``Codetable`` doesn't implement ``CodetablePayload``?

Comment: I mean, I would return ``CodetablePayload`` instead of ``CodetablePayload`` (if you don't have some constraints of course).

Comment: projection https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections take entity and put it in a dto or interface...

Comment: i didn't know that feature :)

Answer (score 0):

Try it with a DTO - [Class Based Projection](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections.dtos). I know that interface based projections work well with native queries. I dont know how they work with JPQL especially since the column names were translated to col_0_0_ and so on.

DTO Projections also have the advantage that you get an error if it cant find the right constructor. You have also the possibility to debug the constructor. And you can inside the constructor created other objects.